# String to Object as Expression

Tags: vb.net

I have multiple TextBox controls `Monday` that will hold a value. I want to be able to add up all of the `Monday` textboxes and store that value as `monTotal`. I am getting an error message that says string cannot be converted to integer.

```
    For i As Integer = 1 To rowCount Step 1
        Dim var As Object
        var = "txtMonday" & i & ".Text"
        monTotal = monTotal + CInt(var)
    Next
```

Comment: Sooo, var is an object but when you set it on that next line it may as well be a string. If anything you may want to try to find a way to retrieve the actual control and cast to a TextBox and then you can call the .Text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are attempting to obtain a reference to the text boxes is not idiomatic of VisualBasic .NET.

```
var = "txtMonday" & i & ".Text"     ' this is not a way to obtain a reference to the text box's text
```

While it would be possible to accomplish something like that using reflection, you'd be much better off refactoring your code to use an array of text boxes.

Since you are probably using Windows Forms you could perhaps implement logic to find the text box control you are interested in on the form using something like this:

```
' assuming container is the control that contains the text boxes    
For Each ctrl In container.Controls
  If (ctrl.GetType() Is GetType(TextBox)) Then
      If ctrl.Name.StartsWith("txtMonday") Then
         Dim txt As TextBox = CType(ctrl, TextBox)
         monTotal = monTotal + CInt(txt.Text)
      End If
  End If
Next
```

The example above assumes that all the `txtMonday..` text boxes are placed inside a control named `container`. That could be the form itself, or some other panel or table.

Comment: I agree, there has to be a cleaner way for you to retrieve your values.

Comment: The reason I have the for loop is because the user can click an "Add row" button which adds another row, and therefore adds another text box and I wont know how many text boxes there are. Will I am be able to use textbox arrays in this situation?

Comment: @user1695996 - yes, that's a perfect use case for using an array or List<T> to store the collection of text boxes. Each time you add a text box to the UI, you also add it to the list. Then you go through the list and compute the total.

Answer (score 0):

If all the textboxes live on the form and there are none being used for other text work you could use this. You could place all the textboxes that contain values your looking for in a separate container and get them like below, but use that control collection.

```
Dim amount As Double = 0
For Each tb As Textbox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Textbox)()
  amount += Convert.ToDouble(tb.Text)
Next
```

Comment: your code will sum values of all text box in the form..if he has any textbox which he don't need to add in the summation.it will fails. check with text box name also..

Comment: No kidding - there is a disclaimer for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim monTotal as double=0 

 For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox AndAlso ctrl.Name.StartsWith("txtMonday") Then
                   monTotal = monTotal + val(ctrl.Text) 
            End If

 Next
```